Why did Shiva rape Mohini?
Someone pointed out to me how Shiva raped Mohini. He cited verse 8.12.26-30 in the Srimad Bhagavatam where Shiva became lustful and raped Mohini. Is there any explanation for this?

It was a lila to give birth to Harihara @vedantkavaipatti

There was no resistance so that was not rape..

@Nitesh But it says that she was unwilling and bashful and he grabbed her by her braid

Srimad Bhagavatam mentions this incident, and does not mention rape at all. Rather it is fun and play between them. I do note Shri Ayappa is the son of Shri Shiva and Shri Mohini, and so she is likely his spiritual wife which is why he caught her hair when he was infatuated with her.

But it says that she was unwilling and bashful but Shiva grabbed her by her braid to have his way

Personally, nearly all scriptures have been interpolated and verses and hardly the same in any scripture. Madhvacarya noted this himself.
The Shri Shiva Mohini incident does not denote rape. Her bashfulness shows this is a lila, otherwise she would be afraid and would run away. Since they are eternal husband and wife, and Shri Vishnu is Shri Mohini herself, it can only be considered playfulness.

Thank you for clearing

Here is the written answer
If you want this ans in video format
here is a vid i found that will help you Video
